# invalid character 'personal_signAndSendTransaction' after top-level value

Tags: mist, accounts

I am getting this error when I try to sign in to one of my accounts using Mist. If I try to unlock the account using the console I get this error:

> invalid character 'g' after top-level value

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your contract code?

Comment: @richard-horrocks Are you sure thats relevant? I have never had a problem with the contract before

Comment: @richard-horrocks edited

Comment: I have tried it with other contacts and I get the same error so I dont see how it can be related to the contract code

Comment: Okay, if it's _all_ of your contracts, and they're sufficiently different from each other, then as you say, it may not be related to contract code itself.

Comment: I cant say its all my contracts as I have quite a few but I have tried a fair number of very different contracts

Comment: It's definitely not a problem with your contract. It may be an issue with the way you are trying to interact with the contract, but it's more likely a bug in the wallet client. You should submit a bug report on github with more details.

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues